# linux string-replace for mac os x i.e. sed with no regex

Tags: linux, macos, sed, osx-yosemite

i have an old script on which replaces strings in files using the 'replace' command e.g.

```
    newname=`echo "$f" | replace "${OLD}" "${NEW}"`
```

this used to run on mac os x (all versions up to yosemite). I remember finding this as a non-regex processing version of sed i.e. you don't need to escape all the regex bits of the string. it definitely exists under linux (http://linux.die.net/man/1/replace).

i had to rebuild my mac (os x yosemite) and cannot for the life of me find this command. have tried

- googling but everything points to sed!
- tried some of the gnu utility packages in brew e.g. coreutils

nothing - i'm sure it used to exist!?

any pointers gratefully received!

Comment: On my 10.11.2 El Capitan machine, there is a `replace` in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/replace`.  Do you have that around?  (It's also 3.3 MiB of binary.)  I've not checked exactly what it does, but running `replace --version` yields
`replace: No to-string for last from-string` which looks promising.

Comment: thanks Jonathan - i don't have mysql install on my machine. will have  alook though